# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'sorted' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am implementing a kind of a quizlet web app. I get the first for loop to run, however on the nested for loop I always get jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'sorted' is undefined. Even though the variable is defined globally.

```
This is the html template part which throws the error:
    {% for question_text, answer_list in question_answers.items() %}
        <h2>{{ question_text }}</h2>
        <form id="question_{{ loop.index }}" method="POST">
            {% for i, (answer_text, is_correct) in enumerate(sorted(answer_list)) %}
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{ chr(ord('a') + i) }}" />
                    {{ chr(ord('a') + i) }}) {{ answer_text }}
                </label><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="answer_list[]" value="{{ answer_text }}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="is_correct_list[]" value="{{ is_correct }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

And this is the python part from my @app.route('/') code

```
    global numOfIncorrectQuestions
    numOfIncorrectQuestions = 0
    global numOfCorrectQuestions
    numOfCorrectQuestions = 0
    global question_answers 
    global question_answers 
    question_answers = {}

 cursor.execute('SELECT question.question, answer.answer, answer.isCorrect FROM question INNER JOIN answer ON question.questionID = answer.questionID ORDER BY RANDOM()')

   for row in cursor:
        question_text, answer_text, is_correct = row
        question_answers.setdefault(question_text, []).append((answer_text, is_correct))

    return render_template('exam.html', numOfIncorrectQuestions=numOfIncorrectQuestions, numOfCorrectQuestions=numOfCorrectQuestions,
question_answers=question_answers)
```

I imported sorted too, though as it did not solve the issue, not really sure, that was really the issue. Thanks for any help on that in advance.

Importing, jinja2, sorted and defining my variables global. Debugged the code, but don't see any obvious mistake.

Comment: Neither `enumerate` nor `sorted` are jinja2 functions. Recall that Jinja is not Python. Take a look at the Jinja documentation for information about [what filter functions are available](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) and [how to define your own](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#writing-filters).

Answer (score 0):

While `sorted()` is Python's built-in, not jinja's, you still can teach it  about it by adding `sorted` to jinja environment as global variable:

```py
app.jinja_env.globals.update(sorted=sorted)
```

Note, that per [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/)

> The Jinja environment used to load templates.
>
> The environment is created the first time this property is accessed. Changing jinja_options after that will have no effect.

so you need to ensure you are setting this up before you try to render any template.